# PostgreSQL identical plans using cache but with different duration?

Tags: java, benchmarking, postgresql-9.6

When I am executing multiple queries (for a benchmark) I obtained this graph (same query executed multiple times), the graph show me that one execution took more time and it was not the firs (ont-shot), can you help me, please?

I attached also the log obtained from my execution for the same query.

[image]

Comment: It's really hard to say without a lot more information. The delay may have been external to PostgreSQL, in which case you'd have to instrument basically the entire server in order to figure out what was causing it. The query seems pretty heavy in general (800ms or so even for the "fast" ones) so it's using a lot of resources (I/O, memory, or both), providing a lot of opportunities for some hiccup to occur.

Comment: I use a big cluster to run this query, the problem is after this query, the execution seems use the cach nicely. How I can be sure that the problem doesn't come from I/O or memory. Because, I had this impression that when the execution process comes to this points the process is stop but It use the same plan?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the process is stop." But PostgreSQL seems to think that all of these queries are identical, so the issue must be either that there's some external delay that causes one to take longer, or there is one server in your cluster that is running slowly (assuming that this log includes the results from the entire cluster).

Comment: ok, si I check the execution and when the process comes to the problematic execution, I see this: "postgres dtsc1 127.0.0.1(46248) idle" and "postgres dtsc1 127.0.0.1(46248) SELECT" for other executions?